# Can I change root's domain name in emails?

Tags: centos, email, root, cpanel

I already changed my root alias to my email so that whenever a email is sent to root, i get a copy of that. Which is perfectly working fine. Now, when i receive an email, the From address is : root @ alpha.myserver.com.

alpha.myserver.com is my server's host name. I just wanted to know if I can change this FROM email address? something like root@mydomain.com?

My server is a cPanel/WHM + CloudLinux server.

Thanks.

Comment: Natively this is perfectly possible. Whether it's possible through cPanel I can't say.

Comment: If you just ignore your webpanel and edit your postfix config, it's possible, however, I have no idea if your webpanel will just overwrite the configuration.